# Find the length of an specific object within an array

Tags: javascript

In the following code there is a console log of `obj['mn']` which returns the length of that specific object which is 2. The problem with the code is that it doesn't count the multidimentional array, and only it counts the first array. The result should be `4` because there are 4 `'mn'` in total. What am I doing wrong?

```
var arr = [['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab'],'mn','mn'];
var obj = { };
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
   if (obj[arr[i]]) {
      obj[arr[i]]++;
   }
}
console.log(obj['mn']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
var arr = [['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab'],'mn','mn'];
var obj = { };

function count(arr, obj) {
    for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
       if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
           count(arr[i], obj);
       }
       else if (typeof obj[arr[i]] !== 'undefined') {
           obj[arr[i]]++;
       }
       else {
           obj[arr[i]] = 1;
       }
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log(count(arr, obj));
```

This is a recursive implementation. When it gets to an array, the recursion get one level deeper.

Comment: This is great but it returns all objects and their lengths, I only need to return one specific object as per my question.

Comment: You can use `var lengths = count(arr, obj);` and then get the one you like: `console.log(lengths['mn']);`

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `obj[['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab']]`, which is obviously not what you wanted.

You need a depth first search.

If `arr[i]` is an array, then you need to loop through that array.